# Triangulation of the complement VS Complement of the triangulation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, triangulation

Consider a triangulable space $X$ in the $n$-sphere $S^n$ whose complement $X^c=S^n\backslash X$ is also triangulable: there exists <del>finite</del> simplicial complexes $T_X$ and $T_{X^c}$ whose geometric realizations $|T_X|$ and $|T_{X^c}|$ (in $S^n$) are respectively homeomorphic to $X$ and $X^c$.

I'm interested in the relation between $|T_X|^c$ and $|T_{X^c}|$: do they have the same homology? (or even stronger, are they homotopy equivalent or homeomorphic?)

If $X$ is compact, I can show (using [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) on $X$ and $|T_X|$), that $|T_X|^c$ and $|T_{X^c}|$ have the same (co)homology. However, I'm precisely interested in the case where $X$ is neither closed nor open.

Any idea?

Comment: Triangulability does *not* require the simplicial complex to be finite.

Comment: And in fact a finite triangulable space is always compact, so if you are interested in $X \subset S^n$ which is neither closed nor open then you will need infinite simplicial complexes for both $X$ and $X^c$.

Comment: Also, $|T_X|^c$ makes no sense. $|T_X|$ is of course the geometric realization of $T_X$. But what is the complement of $|T_X|$? Complement ***in what***?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's true I didn't realize finite triangulability $\implies$ compactness... So this is an ill-posed problem.
I was thinking as $|T_X|$ as a geometric realization in $S^n$ (taking for instance the stereographic projection of the realization in $R^n$). $|T_X|^c$ was then defined as $S^n\backslash |T_X|$.